# AUTO-INCREMENT on non-primary key column using phinx migration library

Tags: php, mysql, database-migration

So as title pretty much describes, I'm trying to utilize phinx for database migration, but I have AUTO-INCREMENT column, which is not used as the primary key. As far as I see, this can't be done with phinx.

I realize, that I could probably do without that column altogether, but it's the part of the huge legacy code and, at the moment at least, I don't have the time to refactor entire app to ensure that column is not used anywhere. If my conclusion is correct and phinx is not able to achieve this, I'd appreciate some alternatives, possessing described functionality

Answer (score 0):

You can use the up and down phinx method to create this table using execute fontion with pure sql.

See [this](https://coderwall.com/p/v3qg2q/complex-database-migrations-with-php-mysql-using-phinx)